# function parameter for css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, parameters

im trying to create a function to help me change some css without having to repeat the code every time.

this is my code:

```
function error(e){
         e.css({
          'border':'2px solid red',
          'background-color':'rgba(250,52,5,.2)'
         })
}
```

as you can see i'm adding the (e) parameter, so i can apply the function to any element.

the function works fine but im getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
    at error (scripts1.js:83)

there's any other or a better way to do this?
sorry about my english and this simple question, im a begginer as you can see.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `$(e).css(...)`

Comment: What do you pass as `e` for `error`? In other words, how do you call `error`?

Comment: The problem is in the place where you're calling `error()`, not in the function itself. You need to show that code.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thats exactly the problem! Thanks!
there was an syntax error when i called the function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not passing any value into your function.  So you are getting undefined error.

I would suggest for you to setup a class for error in your style sheets like:

```
.error  {
      border:2px solid red;
      background-color:rgba(250,52,5,.2);
     }
```

Now whenever you get an error, just set the class on the element:

```
 function error (e) {
   $(e).addClass('error');
 }
```

Please ensure that you are passing a Dom element to the error function.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of .css and use .addClass. Define the class in your style sheet.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind next time, seems like the simplest way to doit, than you